# The number $A$ consists of nine non-zero digits.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Please help me to solve this task about number theory.
I tried to solve but i can not figure it out.
The number $A$ consists of nine non-zero digits. An eight-digit number consisting of identical digits was added to it. The result is a nine-digit number $B$. It turned out that the number $B$ can be obtained from the number $A$ by rearranging some digits. What is the smallest digit that $B$ can start with if the last digit of $A$ is $3$?

Comment: What does it mean that an 8-digit number consist of identical digits with a 9-digit number?

Comment: @frabala: I think that this $8$-digit number is of the form $X = x \cdot 11111111.$ (all its digits are the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote this $8$-digital number as $X$.
Then
$$
X = x\cdot 11111111,$$
where $1\le x \le 9$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are built of the same set of digits, we conclude that their difference $B-A$ is divisible by $9$.

Denote:

 $a$ - sum of digits of $A$;
 $b$ - sum of digits of $B$. Then

$$A \equiv a (\bmod 9)$$
$$B \equiv b (\bmod 9)$$
$$B-A \equiv 0 (\bmod 9)$$

So $X$ is divisible by $9$. Therefore $x=9$, hence 
$$X=99999999.$$

---

So 
$$
B = A + 100000000 - 1.
$$

Can you continue from here?
Which (only) digits of $A$ have been changed after adding number $X$?

Can the leading digit of $B$ be $2$? Why?

Can the leading digit of $B$ be $3$? Example?

Comment: maybe the last digit

Comment: @art1488: yes, sure; and? (which one else?)

Comment: @art1488: since the last digit of $A$ is $3$, the last digit of $B$ is $2$. What about all the middle digits of the number $A$? feel free to check it on any valid examples

Comment: and the first digit of $A$

Comment: @art1488: great!

Comment: @Oleg567but what can be the first digit of $B$?

Comment: it turns out that A is 99999999 less than B then we can get B by rearranging the digits of the  A?

Comment: If denote $A$ as
$$A = \overline{\color{red}{x}\color{gray}{\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet}\color{blue}{3}}$$ and  $B$ as
$$B = \overline{\color{blue}{y}\color{gray}{\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet}\color{red}{2}}$$ (all the gray digits will remain without changes). And remember that $B$ is constructed of just rearranged digits of $A$.

Comment: oh yes yes I understood everything) my calculator did not count correctly) it was obvious))) thanks for helping

Comment: @art1488: you're welcome)

Comment: i've one more question please give me some hints

Comment: Bob added $17$ numbers whose decimal notation uses the same digit $N$ and no other digits are used. What is the smallest number greater than $2052201300$ he could get?

Comment: @art1488: I'll try to answer a bit later